# Can electrons jump between levels in same shell with constant $L$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, angular-momentum, atomic-physics

I see many cases where electrons jump from various energy levels of some $L$ value to various levels of other $L$ value. But is there any transition in same $L$ level between its different orientations?
$EDIT $
(How to calculate energy difference?)

Answer (score 1):

They can, following [selection rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule). As an example the [line of hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line) $\lambda=21 cm$ corresponds to a transition with $\Delta L=0, \Delta S=1$